# iPhone 6 ValidatorEnable is not defined

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios8

We have an Asp.net web application, we are using jQuery mobile for mobile versions.

Our application is running fine in all mobile devices except iPhone 6.
In iPhone 6 we are getting an error (when observed from Chrome console, selected device iPhone6) as "ValidatorEnable is not defined"

The below is the piece of code that gets called on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            $('.myvehicle').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('.OL_AddVehicle').slideUp('fast');
                    EnableSelectVehicleValidators(true);
                    EnableAddVehicleValidators(false);
                }
            });

            $('#AddVehicle').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('.OL_AddVehicle').slideDown('fast');
                    EnableAddVehicleValidators(true);
                    EnableSelectVehicleValidators(false);
                }
            });

            function EnableSelectVehicleValidators(enable) {
                ValidatorEnable($('#<%= ValVehicleItems.ClientID %>').get(0), enable);
        }

        function EnableAddVehicleValidators(enable) {
            ValidatorEnable($('#<%= reqYear.ClientID %>').get(0), enable);
            ValidatorEnable($('#<%= reqMake.ClientID %>').get(0), enable);
            ValidatorEnable($('#<%= reqModel.ClientID %>').get(0), enable);
        }

        <% if(rptGarageVehicles.Items.Count > 0)
           {%>
        EnableAddVehicleValidators(false);
          <%}else{%>
            EnableSelectVehicleValidators(false);   // THis line gets called when the page loads and getting error validatorenable is not defined.
          <%}%>
    });
})(jQuery);


//]]>
```

Very strange that this issue is occurring only on iPhone6/5 with ios8 version.

Any pointers could be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            $('.myvehicle').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('.OL_AddVehicle').slideUp('fast');
                    EnableSelectVehicleValidators(true);
                    EnableAddVehicleValidators(false);
                }
            });

            $('#AddVehicle').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('.OL_AddVehicle').slideDown('fast');
                    EnableAddVehicleValidators(true);
                    EnableSelectVehicleValidators(false);
                }
            });

            function EnableSelectVehicleValidators(enable) {
                ValidatorEnable($("#<%=ValVehicleItems.ClientID%>")[0], enable);
        }

        function EnableAddVehicleValidators(enable) {
            ValidatorEnable($("#<%=reqYear.ClientID%>")[0], enable);
            ValidatorEnable($("#<%=reqMake.ClientID%>")[0], enable);
            ValidatorEnable($("#<%=reqModel.ClientID%>")[0], enable);
        }

        <% if(rptGarageVehicles.Items.Count > 0)
           {%>
        EnableAddVehicleValidators(false);
          <%}else{%>
            EnableSelectVehicleValidators(false);   
          <%}%>
    });
})(jQuery);


//]]>
</script>
```

possibly

```
----------------------------------------------------
function EnableSelectVehicleValidators(enable) {
                ValidatorEnable($("#<%=ValVehicleItems.ClientID%>").get(0), enable);
        }

        function EnableAddVehicleValidators(enable) {
            ValidatorEnable($("#<%=reqYear.ClientID%>").get(0), enable);
            ValidatorEnable($("#<%=reqMake.ClientID%>").get(0), enable);
            ValidatorEnable($("#<%=reqModel.ClientID%>").get(0), enable);
        }
----------------------------------------------------
```